# Is there a way to add another variable to site object in jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I'm creating a blog just to dump my notes in. I love how far I can go with `site.tags` and `site.categories`. All I really need now is the ability to have another filter option. Something li `site.sublog` it would help me create exactly what I need

So here's a post

```
---
layout: post
title: "Angular.js With Codeschool:part five"
date: 2015-05-14 07:57:01 +0100
category: [Angularjs-codeschool, basics]
tags: [angular with codeschool]
sublog: [web]
---
```

Basically I want to write notes on everything I am interested in: web, general tech, history ... and sort of create sub blogs

There are ways around it but now that I am here I just wanted to know if such a thing was possible

Answer (score 0):

[Categories and tags](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#categories-and-tags) are treated specially by Jekyll, so you won't find that other front matter entries from a post will be collected into a site-wide variable like `site.categories` and `site.tags` are.

The Jekyll documentation has a tutorial on [retrieving items based on front matter properties](https://jekyllrb.com/tutorials/navigation/#scenario-8-retrieving-items-based-on-front-matter-properties), which shows how to iterate over an entire collection and do some per-item processing based on a front matter variable's value.

You could [iterate](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/tags/iteration/) over your collection, inspecting the `sublog` values of each item and [`concat`](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/filters/array-filters#concat)-ing them to a list of all known `sublog` values (perhaps removing duplicates using [`uniq`](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/filters/array-filters#uniq) afterwards, and optionally [`sort`](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/filters/array-filters#sort)-ing them before further processing).

This would enable you to create a list of all sub blogs, and for each sub blog, create a list of posts within it (which is presumably your end goal).

Answer (score -1):

You can store Sitewide information + configuration settings in _config.yml.

Your example shows Page specific information in the YAML front matter!

Read the [Jekyll Documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/), please.

Comment: That's different to what I am asking. In the link you provided we have `site.tags.TAG`. So the `TAG` comes from what we specify in YAML. I'm asking is there a way to add another "tag" like variable? So `site.series.Series` So in each post I add `series: X` and the get those values using `{% for series in site.series %}`. 

So {% tag in site.tags %}` works, is there a way to add `site.series` (or what ever name I want)

Comment: Yes, no problem. You can sitewide or page specific add far as you like so many variables. And you can nested variables as array, hash, ... . Read the [Yaml Cookbook](http://yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html) for more informations, please.

Comment: "You can sitewide ..." what's what I am asking how to do.